# How to change max number of test cases generated by hypothesis?

Tags: python, automated-tests, property-based-testing, python-hypothesis

The famous property-based testing framework hypothesis is capable to generate massive test case.

But is there any way to restrict the quantity of test case generated by hypothesis in order to make testing period shorter?

For example feeding specific keyword argument to `@given` decorator?

Answer (score 8):

It depends on whether you want to restrict for one test or for all, but approach is similar and based on [settings](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#settings).

## Configuring single test

To change default behavior for some of tests we can decorate them with [`settings` object](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#hypothesis.settings) like

```py
from hypothesis import given, settings, strategies


@given(strategies.integers())
@settings(max_examples=10)
def test_this_a_little(x):
    ...


@given(strategies.integers())
@settings(max_examples=1000)
def test_this_many_times(x):
    ...
```

for `test_this_a_little` there will be `10` examples generated (at most) and for `test_this_many_times` there will be `1000`.

## Configuring all tests

To change default behavior for all tests somewhere during bootstrap of your test run (e.g. for `pytest` it can be [`conftest.py` module](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/plugins.html?highlight=re#conftest-py-local-per-directory-plugins)) we can define a custom `hypothesis` settings profile and then use it during tests invocation like

```py
from hypothesis import settings

settings.register_profile('my-profile-name',
                          max_examples=10)
```

and after that (assuming that you are using `pytest`)

```sh
> pytest --hypothesis-profile=my-profile-name
```

## Further reading

`hypothesis` is pretty awesome and allows us to configure many things, available options are listed [in the docs](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#available-settings).

Comment: Doesn't `max_examples` still allow more than one test in some conditions?